# Changing value of a form control in an embedded dynamic form component

Tags: angular

Using Angular's dynamic form implementation, I am trying to set a form control's value from outside the actual form component. I have prepared a Stackblitz to show what I want to achieve: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng8-form-select-from-outside . When the user clicks the "select solid" button, I want the second form control's value to switch to "solid". I have tried multiple ways to achieve this, but every time it ends with not having access to the FormGroup, because the parent does not have access to that.

Any idea how I can achieve this? Unfortunately, I cannot move the button into the DynamicFormComponent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form is initiated in **DynamicFormComponent** and you can access it from **AppComponent** with **ViewChild** decorator.
Add this to **AppComponent**

```
@ViewChild(DynamicFormComponent, {static: true}) dynamicFormComponent: DynamicFormComponent;
```

And you'll be able to get form and work with it like

```
this.dynamicFormComponent.form
```

Comment: Thank you, that is what I was looking for. I have updated the Stackblitz for reference.