# How can I receive the values from a form in the parent component?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a template with two components in it.
Both components are forms and will be filed in the template.

Now I want to receive the values from the forms in the parent component and check if the forms are valid. Then I want to enable the button to submit the value of both forms.

The template looks like this:

```
<section>
  <app-first-form></app-first-form>
  <app-second-form></app-second-form>

  <button [disabled]="first-form.invalid || second-form.invalid"> submit</button>
</section>
```

The tstemplate from one of the forms:

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="submitForm()">
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Vorname</mat-label>
    <input
      matInput
      formControlName="name"
      name="name">
  </mat-form-field>
  <button
    type="submit"
    [disabled]="form.invalid">submit Form
  </button>
</form>
```

The ts file from one of the forms:

```
export class OneOfTheForms implements OnInit {

  form: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      name: [null, Validators.required],
    });
  }
}
```

Would be great if someone could show me how to do this. Thanks!

Comment: use @output in both form components and send the event to parent component

Comment: or you can access both forms with @ViewChild decorator, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64053192/11900833)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that with `@Output()` on both elements or `@ViewChild()` handling everything inside the ParentComponent. I would suggest to use `@ViewChild` and handle the 2 forms there.

Have created a **[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-parent-form?file=src/app/app.component.html)** for your reference.

**ParentComponent**

```
@Component({...})
export class ParentComponent {

  @ViewChild(Form1Component) form1: Form1Component;
  @ViewChild(Form2Component) form2: Form2Component;
  
  body: any;

  constructor() {}

  // Check if both forms are valid after validating that this.form1 and this.form2 already exists
  get isFormValid(): boolean {
    if (this.form1 && this.form2) return this.form1.form.valid && this.form2.form.valid;
  }

  save(): void {
    const { value: form1Values } = this.form1.form;       // Get form1 form values
    const { value: form2Values } = this.form2.form;       // Get form2 form values

    // If both forms are valid, assign and merge result inside the body
    if (this.isFormValid) this.body = {...form1Values, ...form2Values};
  }

}
```

> Both the Form1 and Form2 Components don't have any Submit buttons, we only have 1 submit button and it's on the ParentComponent which checks their form status and fetches their form values.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 0):

another aproach using template reference variables (it's the same that use viewChild but only using html). Remember that by defect all the variables of a components are public. If you use a template reference variable you can "get" all the variables

```
<section>
  <app-first-form #first></app-first-form>
  <app-second-form #second></app-second-form>

  <button [disabled]="first.form.invalid || second.form.invalid"> submit</button>
</section>
<pre>
{{first.form?.value}}
{{second.form?.value}}
</pre>
```