# Simplest way to share a variable between angular components

Tags: angular, variables, web-component

I have a button which suppose to change a boolean variable from true to false and vice versa, like a switch. the variable and the button are in different components, how is that possible to share the variable if they components are not parent-child?

Comment: See this: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Comment: if they are "at time" in the app, you can also use a template reference variable to "get" one component -and to all his variables- see, e.g. this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64302591/how-can-i-receive-the-values-from-a-form-in-the-parent-component/64304615#64304615)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a service. This is outlined here: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

You can use a `Subject` (no starting value) or a `BehviorSubject` (has a starting value) to hold the data, and another property to expose the value as an `Observable` that components can subscribe to.

Example:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class YourServiceClass {

  private _yourValue = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
  yourValue$: Observable<boolean>;

  constructor() {
    this.yourValue$ = this._yourValue.asObservable();
  }

  toggleYourValue(): void {
    this._yourValue.next(!this._yourValue.getValue());
  }

}
```

Then in your component(s) you would inject the service and set up a subscription to populate a property on your component, which can be used elsewhere in your code or bound to the template...

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-your-component',
  template: `Your value is: {{ yourValue }}`
})
export class YourComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  subscription: Subscription;
  yourValue: boolean;
  
  constructor(
    private readonly yourServiceClass: YourServiceClass,
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.subscription = 
      this.yourServiceClass.yourValue$.subscribe(yourValue => {
      this.yourValue = yourValue;
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }

}
```

Comment: Ok so this is how I declare the variable, and how do I access it in another component?

Comment: You would need to subscribe to `yourServiceClass.yourValue$` in components.

Comment: Can you explain how to do that?

Comment: Sure. I'll add some example code for you.

Comment: Successfully shared the variable, if I change the value from false to true in the code it works but if calling toggleYourValue() the changes appear only in first component, in second it always stays false.

Comment: I would have to see exactly what you're doing. To change the value of `yourValue`, you should be calling the service method `toggleYourValue()`. That will change the value available to all subscribers. Are you doing manual change detection?

Comment: The 'yourValue' variable is declared in first component .ts file, 'toggleYourValue()' called in first component .html file by a button click, change doesn't appear is second component .ts file. This is first time doing this kind of a task.

Comment: Ping me at alsoicode@gmail.com and let's hop on a Google video call. Much easier than going back on forth via comments :)

Answer (score 4):

So basically, there are three kinds of sharing data between components

1. @Input, @ViewChild - this kind of communication is used when components are parent-child in an HTML template
2. @Injectable (services, tokens) - use this when components are located in different trees
3. Routing data - that's data available via Router, usually used when the component is placed in router-outlet

Less-used techniques are

4. Using template reference, see
   [How can I receive the values from a form in the parent component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64302591/how-can-i-receive-the-values-from-a-form-in-the-parent-component/64304615#64304615)
5. Kind of Mediator approach when special directives can have access
   to shared data, see [NgSwitch](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/main/packages/common/src/directives/ng_switch.ts)

Comment: you forgot using a template variable

Comment: That's technique used with directives to enrich another component with smth, but not to exchange data. But yeah, probably I will add it